# Preciso que pelo menos um desses campos seja obrigatório marcar

Tags: php, html, css

Boa tarde, preciso que ao preencher os dados, pelo menos uma dessas opções seja colocada como marcação obrigatória, não tenho muito conhecimento na área, pode ser algo simples, mas estou apanhando rs rs! Este é o código, aonde estou tentando alterar, coloquei um "Required" dentro das input, porém obriga a marcar a caixa, mesmo se não possuir o dado..

````
    <div class="selectBox" onclick="showCheckboxes()">
      <div class="overSelect"></div>
    </div>
        
        <div class="form-group col-md-3">
          <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
            <label class="form-check-label">Dados que possui no documento?</label><br>
          </div> 
        </div>      

                <div id="checkboxes">
                
      <label for="tem_cnpj">
        <input type="checkbox" id="tem_cnpj" name="tem_cnpj"/>&nbsp;Tem CNPJ?&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
      <label for="tem_cpf">
        <input type="checkbox" id="tem_cpf" name="tem_cpf"/>&nbsp;Tem CPF?&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
      <label for="tem_rg">
        <input type="checkbox" id="tem_rg" name="tem_rg"/>&nbsp;Tem RG?&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
      <label for="tem_nome">
        <input type="checkbox" id="tem_nome" name="tem_nome"/>&nbsp;Tem nome?&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
      <label for="tem_e-mail">
        <input type="checkbox" id="tem_email" name="tem_email"/>&nbsp;Tem e-mail?&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
      <label for="tem_endereco">
        <input type="checkbox" id="tem_endereco" name="tem_endereco"/>&nbsp;Tem endereço?&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
      <label for="tem_telefone">
        <input type="checkbox" id="tem_telefone" name="tem_telefone"/>&nbsp;Tem telefone?&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
      <label for="nenhum">
        <input type="checkbox" id="nenhum" name="nenhum"/>&nbsp;Nenhum</label>              
                
                </div>      
                    </div> ```


[![Marcar pelo menos uma das opções para validar][2]][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OcRT.jpg
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3ssw.png
````

Comment: Boa tarde Gustavo, acredito que você possa usar o atributo checked, você coloca em uma das inputs e sempre que atualizar ela vai estar selecionada, mas da pra ticar outras e tirar desse input também, olha a documentação da MDN : [Mozzila](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/checkbox)

Comment: Obrigado! Pena que ao colocar o checked ela já vem automaticamente marcado, posso estar sendo bem leigo rs rs, mas precisaria que se nenhuma das informações fosse marcada, constasse o bloqueio/mensagem solicitando marcar ao menos uma opção

Comment: descubra como fazer uma boa pergunta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask e o guia de sobrevivência no SOpt https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8045/guia-de-sobreviv%C3%AAncia-do-stack-overflow-em-portugu%C3%AAs

Answer (score 0):

Você pode adicionar um script Javascript pra validar esse seu requisito. Algo do tipo:

```js
function validarCheckGroup(){
  if(document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length == 0){
    alert('Selecione ao menos uma opção!');
  } else {
    alert('Pelo menos uma opção foi Selecionada!');
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Exemplo</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="selectBox" onclick="showCheckboxes()">
      <div class="overSelect"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
      <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <label class="form-check-label">Dados que possui no documento?</label><br>
      </div> 
    </div>      

    <div id="checkboxes">
      <label for="tem_cnpj">
        <input type="checkbox" id="tem_cnpj" name="tem_cnpj"/>&nbsp;Tem CNPJ?&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
      <label for="tem_cpf">
        <input type="checkbox" id="tem_cpf" name="tem_cpf"/>&nbsp;Tem CPF?&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
      <label for="tem_rg">
        <input type="checkbox" id="tem_rg" name="tem_rg"/>&nbsp;Tem RG?&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
      <label for="tem_nome">
        <input type="checkbox" id="tem_nome" name="tem_nome"/>&nbsp;Tem nome?&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
      <label for="tem_e-mail">
        <input type="checkbox" id="tem_email" name="tem_email"/>&nbsp;Tem e-mail?&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
      <label for="tem_endereco">
        <input type="checkbox" id="tem_endereco" name="tem_endereco"/>&nbsp;Tem endereço?&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
      <label for="tem_telefone">
        <input type="checkbox" id="tem_telefone" name="tem_telefone"/>&nbsp;Tem telefone?&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
      <label for="nenhum">
        <input type="checkbox" id="nenhum" name="nenhum"/>&nbsp;Nenhum</label>        
    </div>
    <input type="submit" onclick="validarCheckGroup()"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

Validação no front-end não substitui validação no back-end. Sempre é importante validar as informações que chegam no seu back-end, já que você não tem controle sobre a interface que foi usada pra lhe enviar os dados.

Comment: Muito Obrigado!